# IntelliJ does not use JUnit import in Integration Tests (Gradle project)

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle, junit, dependencies, resolve

I have a predefined project structure with a working Gradle dependency management and the following Gradle JUnit resolving:

```
dependencies {
    [...]
    testCompile "junit:junit:${versions.junit}"
    integrationTestCompile "junit:junit:${versions.junit}"
}
```

The project structure is

```
<project>
    <module>
        src
            integration-test
            main
            test
```

Now, while the `test` classes compile well in IntelliJ, the `integrationTest` classes still don't. On ...

```
import org.junit.Assert;
```

... I am told: "Cannot resolve symbol 'Assert'.

As an IntelliJ (and also Gradle) newbie, I am quite confused about handling this problem. While [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19278253/4420271) tells me that I could map both, `testCompile` and `integrationTestCompile` to IDEA's `test` scope (without describing how), [that answer](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/intellij-dependencies-not-appearing-with-custom-configuration/5757/2) refers to the Gradle IdeaModule documentation, but that is not very explanatory at all at this point.

So, what is the right or best approach and what exactly has to be done?

Comment: Is the problem occurring only with IntelliJ or do you get errors from running integration tests outside of IntelliJ?

Comment: @EricWendelin Thanks for cooperativeness! See answer below. Any open questions to you?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was meanwhile solved by:

A) In build.gradle type:

```
configurations {
    provided
    testCompile.extendsFrom provided
    integrationTestCompile.extendsFrom testCompile
    integrationTestRuntime.extendsFrom testRuntime
    [...]
}
```

B) [Gradle Refresh](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/gradle-tool-window.html)